# How to find count null fields for all keys in document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo with multiple fields, I need to find out number of null values for each field in all documents? Also I need to do it using aggregation pipelines.
For Example if my collection be like this:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   field1: 'value1',
   field2: 'value2',
   field3: null,
   field4: 'value3'
},
   _id: 2,
   field1: null,
   field2: 'value4',
   field3: null,
   field4: 'value5'
{
   _id: 3,
   field1: 'value7',
   field2: 'value8',
   field3: 'value9',
   field4: 'value10'
},
{
   _id: 4,
   field1: 'value11',
   field2: 'value12',
   field3: null,
   field4: 'value13'
}
```

I want to get such result:

```
{ fieldName: 'field1', notNullCount: 3},  { fieldName: 'field2', notNullCount: 4}, { fieldName: 'field3', notNullCount: 1}, { fieldName: 'field4', notNullCount: 4}
```

I've tried to use projection and using condition to count not null values, but the result I've gotten is one document with fieldName as key and count as value, but **I need to get a result with one document for each field as my above example.**

(In the case you want to know why I need such result, because I need to run the query on Metabase and creating dashboards and it only support such results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `$group` with `_id: null` so that you're able to aggregate over all of the fields.

```
  { $group: {
      _id: null,
      field1: { $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$field1", null]}, 0, 1] } },
      field2: { $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$field1", null]}, 0, 1] } }
     }
  }
```

Once you have those documents, you can `$project` them into an array that you can `$unwind` to get your desired format:

```
{ $project: { fields: [{ fieldName: "field1", count: "$field1" }, {fieldName: "field2", count: "$field2"}] } },
{ $unwind: "$fields" }
```

Comment: i would add that you should use $eq null and field value for the case that your field value resolves to false.

Comment: Good call! Updated

Comment: I know this query and As I've mentioned, I need to result be 1 document per field as the example question. The query you've written will result just one document in this format `{field1: 1, field2: 2}` that I don't want.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood. In that case, once you've grouped, I believe you'll want to `$project` those rows in an array, and then `$unwind` them. Let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks, Great Idea to project and then unwind, But it's not the exact result I wanted. (Now each document has a `fields` field with fieldName and count, It needs another project to be the exact) But It solved my issue.